# Loop through 2 recordsets to create HTML table in an email

Tags: html, vba, loops, ms-access

I am using Office 365 and trying to create an HTML email from an Access database.  I want to generate a table that iterates through 2 record sets.  The first recordset is a query displaying "Issues" and the second recordset is a query displaying countermeasures for the issues with a one-to-many relationship between the two.  This is how I want to display the tables:

```
<TABLE>
    <TH>Header from Access Table 1 – issue #1</TH>
    <TR>Row from Access Table 1– issue #1</TR>
    <TH>Header from Access Table 2 – CM # 1</TH>
    <TR>Row from Access Table 2 – CM # 1</TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE>
    <TH>Header from Access Table 1 – issue #2</TH>
    <TR>Row from Access Table 1– issue #2</TR>
    <TH>Header from Access Table 2 – CM # 2</TH>
    <TR>Row from Access Table 2 – CM # 2</TR>
</TABLE>
```

But I am getting:

```
<TABLE>
    <TH>Header from Access Table 1 – issue #1</TH>
    <TR>Row from Access Table 1– issue #1</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE>
    <TH>Header from Access Table 1 – issue #2</TH>
    <TR>Row from Access Table 1– issue #2</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE>
     <TH>Header from Access Table 2 – CM # 2</TH>
     <TR>Row from Access Table 2 – CM # 2</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get my code looping properly?

```
     strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM qryZoneIssue " & _
                    " WHERE qryZoneIssue.ZoneMeetingID = " & HoldMeetingID

                '*********** display issues & CMs
                    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2, dbOpenDynaset)
                    rs2.MoveFirst
                    Do While Not rs2.EOF

           strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TABLE Border=""1"", Cellspacing=""0""><TR>" & _
           "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">No.&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
           "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">KPI&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
           "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Ranking&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
           "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">RPS Started&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
           "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Issue Details&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
              "</TR>"
                                ' add the data to the table
                                 strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TR>" & _
                     "<TD align=center width=""10%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneIssueNo].Value & "</TD>" & _
                     "<TD align=center width=""15%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneKPI].Value & "</TD>" & _
                     "<TD align=center width=""10%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneRankID].Value & "</TD>" & _
                     "<TD align=center width=""15%"">" & rs2.Fields![RPSStarted].Value & "</TD>" & _
                     "<TD align=left width=""50%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneIssue].Value & "</TD>" & _
                                 "</TR>"

            strSQL3 = "SELECT * FROM qryZonePermCM " & _
                    " WHERE qryZonePermCM.ZoneMeetingID = " & HoldMeetingID & "AND ZoneIssueID = " & rs2.Fields![ZoneIssueID].Value

                            strBody2 = strBody2 & "</table>"
                            rs2.MoveNext
                            Loop

                    Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL3, dbOpenDynaset)
                    rs3.MoveFirst
                    Do While Not rs3.EOF

           strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TABLE Border=""1"", Cellspacing=""0""><TR>" & _
       "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">CM Details&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
       "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Responsible&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
       "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Target Date&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _

                                ' add the data to the table
                                 strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TR>" & _
                     "<TD align=left width=""40%"">" & rs3.Fields![CMDetails].Value & "</TD>" & _
                     "<TD align=center width=""15%"">" & rs3.Fields![Responsible].Value & "</TD>" & _
                     "<TD align=center width=""10%"">" & rs3.Fields![TargetDate].Value & "</TD>" & _
                                 "</TR>"
                        strBody2 = strBody2 & "</table>"
                       rs3.MoveNext
                            Loop
                        rs3.Close
```

Comment: Your desired output looks more like 1-to-1 since you show only 1 table2 record with each table1 record. Edit question to show example data as text tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to loop second recordset inside loop of first recordset. Also an error in SQL syntax -- need a space in front of AND: `" AND ZoneIssueID = "`. Missing a `</TR>` tag.

Don't start a table for second recordset data.

Consider:

```
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM qryZoneIssue WHERE ZoneMeetingID = " & HoldMeetingID
'*********** display issues & CMs
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2, dbOpenDynaset)
rs2.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs2.EOF
    strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TABLE Border=""1"", Cellspacing=""0""><TR>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">No.&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">KPI&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Ranking&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">RPS Started&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Issue Details&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "</TR>"
    ' add the data to the table
    strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TR>" & _
        "<TD align=center width=""10%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneIssueNo].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD align=center width=""15%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneKPI].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD align=center width=""10%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneRankID].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD align=center width=""15%"">" & rs2.Fields![RPSStarted].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "<TD align=left width=""50%"">" & rs2.Fields![ZoneIssue].Value & "</TD>" & _
        "</TR>"

    strSQL3 = "SELECT * FROM qryZonePermCM WHERE ZoneMeetingID = " & HoldMeetingID & " AND ZoneIssueID = " & rs2!ZoneIssueID

    Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL3, dbOpenDynaset)

    strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TR>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">CM Details&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Responsible&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "<TH Bgcolor=""#2B3856"", Align=""Center""><Font Color=#FFFFFF><b><p style=""font-size:14px"">Target Date&nbsp;</p></Font></TH>" & _
        "</TR>"

    Do While Not rs3.EOF        ' add the data to the table
        strBody2 = strBody2 & "<TR>" & _
            "<TD align=left width=""40%"">" & rs3.Fields![CMDetails].Value & "</TD>" & _
            "<TD align=center width=""15%"">" & rs3.Fields![Responsible].Value & "</TD>" & _
            "<TD align=center width=""10%"">" & rs3.Fields![TargetDate].Value & "</TD>" & _
            "</TR>"
        rs3.MoveNext
    Loop
    strBody1 = strBody1 & strBody2 & "</table>"
    strBody2 = ""
    rs3.Close
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop
rs2.Close
'set email HTMLbody to strBody1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had been struggling with this all week and could not get it quite right.